# restricting size of image that's retrieved from SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, html, image

I'm making a rotating banner system but there is a problem of inconsistent image size display. I am storing the images in a SQL table. I know its bad practice to store images in SQL tables but I am only storing a few files. I need to fix the image display size to be, say, 150 px by 150 px. How do I do this with php? Thanks in advance

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner WHERE id= $id ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $content;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a
            {
                text-decoration:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
require ("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner");
$number = mysql_num_rows($query);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<a href = ' . $row[url] . '> <img src= "get.php?id= ' . $row[id] . ' "/> </a>';
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<a href = ' . $row[url] . '> ' . $row[description] . ' </a>';
}

echo mysql_error();
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is simple just add `width` and `height` attributes to your `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have control over the images and they only ever need to be 150px x 150px I would recommend that you just change the size of them manually and upload them back to your db.

The way you will have to do it now means you'll resize images on the fly everytime the page is loaded which is bad. To get that to work all you do is pass width and height parameters to the img tag like so

`<img src="yourimage" width="150" height="150" />`

Comment: Generally, you want to add width *or* height, not both.  Both will force an aspect ratio break.  Also, clearly I disagree with your sentiment that one has to resize images every time.  That's just silly.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike I said the way he wants to do it now is silly. Ideally he would use a script like you posted or similar to upload and resize images once, making sure the aspect ratio is  kept. Every time he loads the page and pulls the image from the database if it not 150px x 150px it will have to be resized.

Comment: Which is why you cache it.  My script is designed to work in near real-time.  I use a similar script as a general-purpose on demand rescaler.. the only thing is that you want to make sure you cache the images so that it only has to do the work the first time.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike which I agree with. We appear to be arguing the same side here. In an ideal world the OP would be approaching the problem from uploading -> resize once(ever) -> display rather than the situation he has inadvertently got himself in which is resize -> cache -> display which means every now and again when the cache is cleared he will have to resize images again

Comment: That's cool... not trying to pick a fight.  However, I do disagree with your flow.  In most cases, it is best to upload -> store.  From there, you wait until somebody actually wants a given size, then pull from cache or generate.  I designed a social network a few years ago... I think we had 16 different image sizes.  There was generally *no* reason to precompute all 16 sizes immediately, nor store them.  Instead, we just built on-demand servers to size as needed.  That way you can also add/change sizes in the future.  I expect that most large image servers use similar systems in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale your image using an external library call gd.

Although I've never used it, there is a something called [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)();  (I *HAVE* used the rest of this code, btw.... I would just never store an image in a DB).

```
$size = 150;
// This is a reference to your MySQL row.
$img = imagecreatefromstring($row['image_data']);
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$aspect = $height/$width;

// This is a simple width check limiter.  There are dozens of ways to treat this,
// so code away until you get what you want.  Personally, I have a 3K line class to handle
// all of the different ways I may want to change this scaling around.
if ($width < $size) 
{
   $w = $width;
   $h = $height;
}
else 
{
   $w = $size;
   $h = floor($w*aspect);
}

$buffer = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);

// There are some more advanced ways of doing this if you need an alpha channel.
imagecopyresized($buffer,$img,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$width,$height);

// File is now copied and ready to go.  You should save your file with a unique, but 
// reconstructable name.  For instance, if your parameters to get here was 
// 'image.php?image_id=25', I'd actually md5('image.php?image_id=25') and cache it.  In the
// future, you could check your cache to see if the image was there before you even make your
// DB call, which would speed things up greatly.

// I show an example in the code.

//    $filename = '/var/www/public/'.md5('image.php?'.$_SERVER['query_string'].'_'.$size);
$filename = 'test.jpg';
imagejpeg($buffer, $filename, 85 );

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($filename);

imagedestroy($buffer);
imagedestroy($img);
```